# Ubuntu 12.10 not working on my laptop

Tags: 64-bit, intel

I have ASUS K56 c with win7 64-bit intel and i like Ubuntu so I have attempted to see if it will work on my laptop or not and I have downloaded WUBI and it didn't work after installing it and told me their is an error. So I downloaded the 64-bit version and it is written on it AMD so will it work on my laptop??

And if I succeed to install it will it be easy to uninstall it either along side with OS or separate partitions??

Thanks

Comment: What error did the Wubi install give you?

Comment: AMD64 is a confusing name for all 64 bit processors, being AMD or Intel.

Comment: well when i have tried to reboot after istalling it it gave me failed message and need to repair windows to install from cd and thier is an option continue when i press it it gives me the same ansower

Comment: What version of Ubuntu did you install through Wubi? Could you write down the "exact" error message? This could enable someone to help you better.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the 64-bit version will work on an Intel processor, if possible download the torrent version of the .iso file and force a recheck when it's complete to make sure it's ok, then burn the .iso to dvd at slow speed to both last longer and reduce errors...

Comment: i have the DVD and i have burned it in slower speed and i have tried it it is working on try me but i want to intall it on a different partition with out harming the windows so will it be easy to install it and if i want to remove it in the future?????

Answer (score 0):

`amd64` is just the architecture designation, since AMD originally had 64bit, and the original identifier stuck.  `amd64` just means 64-bit processors, both Intel and AMD.  You can safely use the `amd64` version of the software.

Comment: will it be easy to uninstall it from another partition for example or from the main partition??

Comment: if you're installing via 'wubi' that's a different matter, 'wubi' isnt the same as an actual direct-to-partition installation.

Answer (score 0):

It will be "comparatively" easy to remove Ubuntu if you later on decide you don't want it but not a cake walk, no.

If you're having difficulties with Wubi and are not sure whether to do a hard install yet, why not check out Ubuntu in VirtualBox? That way you can become familiar with the concept first before getting your feet wet. Ok, VB has a few difficulties of its own but it's all software related.